# how to import a project's package into an android project?

Tags: android

how can we import a project's package into an android project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can  add the project you want to use in your main project build path.

Steps to do:

1) Select your main project and then Right Click on it and click on `Properties` in the context menu or simply select your main project and press `ALT+ENTER`

2) Now click on the `Java Build Path` in the right pane of the properties window and click on the `Projects`. Here you can find a `Add` button on right side.

3) Click on the add button and select the project of which packages you want to use in your main project and click Ok button.

Now you can use that package or class directly in your main project.

See the picture below:

[image]